# How to fill polygon in image

Tags: image-processing, julia, contour

I've a closed contour region on an image. How to fill it up with white color? Not sure whats the Julia function for fillpoly(..)? Thanks

black background img with thin white circle,
contour=findall(img.>0)
img_With_contour_filled_with_white= ..

Comment: Please provide more context, it is not clear what you are working with.

Comment: If your framework does not supply a polygon filling function, you can craft your own. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/computer_graphics/polygon_filling_algorithm.htm

Answer (score 2):

| Original Img | Filled Img |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |
| [image] | [image] |
| [image] | [image] |
| [image] | [image] |

code:

```
using Images

img = load("img.png")

function fill_poly!(img::Matrix{RGB{N0f8}})
  bit_cols = all.(==(RGB(1., 1., 1.)), eachcol(img)) .== 0
  idx_cols = findall(bit_cols)
  f = findfirst.(!=(RGB(1., 1., 1.)), eachcol(img[:, bit_cols]))
  l = findlast.(!=(RGB(1., 1., 1.)), eachcol(img[:, bit_cols]))
  foreach(x->img[x[1]:x[2], x[3]].=RGB(0., 0., 0.), zip(f, l, idx_cols))
end;

fill_poly!(img)
```

Known issue: fills areas like the following
[image]